# Excel advanced table filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a long list (1000's) of entries in a table in the following form

[Input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZgLJ.png)

I'd like to filter the data so that in the output I get the `guid` groups starting with `Type 1` and all subsequent and all subsequent types.
So if a `guid` group doesn't have `Type 1` in it it shouldn't appear in the output.

The desired output is as under.

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg6IB.png)

Is this possible in Excel at all?

Comment: add a helper column with COUNTIFS based on GUID and Type = 1 - filter to anything > 0

Comment: Please dont post text information as images.

Comment: @RohitGupta how do I paste exccel tables then?

Comment: @RickyTillson Hello I also need the subsequent types if Type 1 is present.

Comment: @RohitGupta I would have also liked the images to be displayed inline, but somehow it shows up as links

Comment: yes, countif would give you subsequent types; you're looking for the presence of the GUID and Type = 1 (hardcoded)

Comment: @RickyTillson if you have the time can you please answer the question.

Comment: @RickyTillson I tried to do it in excel but the guid are random numbers I have shown 4 digit numbers for reference but the numbers could be larger too

Comment: COUNTIFS would still work even if they're true GUIDs and the Type can be any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is probably to add a helper column that looks for the presence of Type1 for a given GUID, this can be achieved with COUNTIFS.

This formula is put into C2 and dragged down. It is for an array with GUIDs in A2:A10 and Types in B2:B10.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A2,$B$2:$B$10,1)
```

This counts the rows with the same GUID as this one and that has Type = 1. It doesn't matter if it is this row or not, just that it has at least 1 instance.

Filter on this new column.

[image: screenshot showing the formula bar and example array]

Comment: this look good, but I didn't understand the `A2` part in the criteria

Comment: A2 means the value from cell A2. So it goes down A2:A10 and thinks are any these the same as A2 which is 7777 (yes, yes, yes, no, no, no, no, no, no, no). Then it goes down B2:B10 and thinks are any of these 1 (yes, no, no, no, no, yes, yes, no, no). It then counts how many times both lists have Yes at the same time. In row 3 you still get HasType1 = 1 because it will still be (Yes, Yes) for row 1 which is the same GUID

Comment: This is amazing!! Thanks for the wonderful explanation!

Comment: Hello! for `7777` its yes, yes, yes, no, no, no, no, no, no, no and for `type` its yes, no, no, no, no, yes, yes, no, no then if its check both columns for yes shouldn't only the first value be yes and the others no.

Comment: For each row of calculation it evaluates all 9 rows in the array A2:B10, so for row two it still evaluates only the first row as (Yes, Yes) but that is what you want, so that it knows that 7777 has a type 1 somewhere. Once you get down to GUID 5555 it evaluates as (no, no, no, yes, no, no, no, no, no) and then (yes, no, no, no, no, yes, yes, no, no) which has 0 rows with (yes, yes)

Comment: if you still don't understand how COUNTIFS works I suggest you read the official documentation, or play around with your data (but leave the formula) and see if you can rationalise it

Comment: Thank you, for your replies!